# How to set specific section header in UITableView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a section header to a section of my UITableView programmatically.

I'm trying to use this code, but it adds the header to all sections. How can I make it only set the first section's header?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "My Section header"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use switch-case makes better code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     switch section {
     case 0: return "Section 0"
     case 1: return "Section 1"
     default: return nil
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0{ // <- apply condition where you wanted to show header or not.
        return "My Section header"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check the section is equal to one

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return (section == 1) ? "Title Header" : nil
}
```

Comment: index starts from 0 not 1.

Comment: it must be section.count == 1